# How to compile a beamer file with a border standalone file

Tags: beamer, standalone

I have a `standalone` file which `documentlass` is `border`. I want to compile that file with my `beamer` file. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by adding a minimal (not) working example that shows what you've got so far and where the issue is.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but can't you use `\includegraphics` to include the pdf which was created from the standalone file?

Comment: If you don't know what a minimal working example (MWE) is,
 see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.

Comment: If you want to turn a beamer slide into a standalone image, use pdfpages.  Alternatively you might be able to modify beamer to add borders.